# How to export a oracle table which consist of blob as a column in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to get a table data which consists of blob as a column, need to export as insert format.

```
create table table1
(id number,
document blob);
```

i tried using **spool** & **/*insert*/** but i'm getting that column as null;

Comment: Have a look at what Jeff says about it: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/05/exporting-multiple-blobs-with-oracle-sql-developer/

Answer (score 4):

Use the sql loader format.

[image]

You'll get each blob downloaded as a file in the specified directory.

[Bonus: use SQLcl from your command prompt to do the same using a bit of js](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2020/07/using-sqlcl-to-write-out-blobs-to-files-in-20-lines-of-js/)

Comment: Is there any way to export as loader format without using SQL Developer but sqlplus or sqlcl?

Comment: Yes, with some javascript you can easily do this with SQLCl. https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2020/07/using-sqlcl-to-write-out-blobs-to-files-in-20-lines-of-js/